# Can someone find the reason why my rectangles do not follow my mouse?

Tags: processing

So down below I have my entire code for a pong game I am programming and although I used mouseY in the y coordinate

```java
fill ( 255, 10, 20 ); rect(x, mouseY + y, 20, 100); // red pong
fill ( 60, 255, 0 ); rect(paddleX, mouseY + y, 20, 100);  // green pong
```

it does not work and I can simply not find my mistake.

Also I am struggling with the Score () part because everytime I try to put

```java
if ( ballX = paddleX ) { score = score + 1;}
```

processing tells me that it is not possible to convert int to Boolean. Can someone please tell me how I can rewrite my code so this error does not appear anymore. What my goal with that part of the code is, is that I want the counter to increase by one every time the ball hits one of the paddles.

full code:

```java
float ballX = 15, ballY = 15, dX = 15, dY = 15; // variables for the ball
float x = 40, y, score = 0;
float paddleX, paddleY = 0; // variables for the paddles
float mouseY, mouseX;
boolean playing = false, gameover = false, finalscore = false, Score = true;  // game states
boolean keyPressed, key;

void setup() {
    size (1500,1100); // the field is going to be 1500x1100px big
    paddleX = width - 40;
}

void keyPressed () { // the game will only start when a key is pressed
    playing = true; 
}

void draw() {
    background(0); // black background

    if (!playing) { // playing = false

        fill(255); textSize(80); textAlign(CENTER); text("Press Space to Play",width/2, height/4);

    fill (255); ellipse (width/2, height/2, 15, 15); // this is the starting point of the ball
    fill (255,10,20); rect(paddleX/58, (height/2)-50, 20, 100);  // red pong
    fill (60,255,0); rect(paddleX, (height/2)-50, 20, 100);  // green pong 

    }  
    if (playing) { // playing = true

        Score();

        fill ( 0, 255, 0 ); ellipse (ballX, ballY, 15, 15); 

        fill ( 255, 10, 20 ); rect(x, mouseY + y, 20, 100); // red pong
        fill ( 60, 255, 0 ); rect(paddleX, mouseY + y, 20, 100);  // green pong

        if ( ballY > height ) { dY = -dY; } // if the ball reaches the lower wall it will bounce off
        if ( ballY < 0 ) { dY = -dY; } // if the ball reaches the upper wall it will bounce off

        ballX = ballX + dX; ballY = ballY + dY;

        if (ballX > width || ballX < 0 ) { gameover = true;}
    } 

    if (gameover) { // gameover = true
        finalscore = true;

        if (keyPressed) { playing = false; }
        else if (playing) { playing = true; }

        if (finalscore) {  // score = true

            fill(255); textSize(45); textAlign(CENTER); text("Game Over. Press a letter to play again.",width/2, height/4);
            fill(255); textSize(80); textAlign(CENTER); text("You scored " + score + " points" ,width/2, (height/4) * 3);

            if (keyPressed) { playing = true;}
        } 
    } 
}

void Score() {

    fill(255); textSize(45); textAlign(CENTER); text(score,width/2, height/4);

    if (playing) {
        if (paddleX <= ballX){ score = score + 1;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're declaring your own `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables at the top of your sketch:

```java
float mouseY, mouseX;
```

**Don't do this.** Processing automatically creates `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables for you. You don't create them yourself. Get rid of this line so that you're using Processing's `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables, not your own.

> Also I am struggling with the Score () part because everytime I try to put

```java
if ( ballX = paddleX ) { score = score + 1;}
```

Look at that `if` statement. You're only using a single `=`, which is an assignment. You need to use two equals `==`, or better yet an inequality like `<=` or `>=`, since the chances of the ball hitting the exact pixel value of the paddle is pretty low.

Comment: and could you also tell me how I make the ball bounce off when it touches the paddles but when it doesn't it just passes though? @KevinWorkman

Comment: @Abigail You're going to have to detect when the ball is colliding with the paddle, and then reverse the direction of the ball. Try something out and post a [mcve] (not your full sketch, just an example sketch) in another question if you get stuck. Good luck.